# mouseover and mouseout misbehaves when Vue JS transition component is used

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, vue.js

I am creating a popup menu as shown below

```js
const menuItem = {
  props: ['name', 'val'],
  data() {
    return {
      showChild: false
    }
  },
  template: /*html */ `
    <div class="nav-item" @mouseover="showChild=true" @mouseout="showChild=false">
        <span v-if="typeof val === 'string' || val instanceof String">
            <a :href="val" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{name}}</a>
        </span>
        <div v-else>
            {{name}}
                <ul class="popup" v-show="showChild">
                    <li v-for="(link, name) in val">
                        <a :href="link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    menuItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menu: {
        'Home': '#',
        'Services': {
          'Software Development': 'https://www.upwork.com/signup/create-account/client_contact_freelancer?ciphertext=~0142999d8b15001517&BYOC',
          'Business Training & Frenchise': 'https://www.badabusiness.com/dd/BIMK003866',
          'Organic Marketing Training & Affiliate Program': 'https://leads-arc.web.app/'
        },
        'Our Apps': {
          'All': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=igM4ChkKEzUwMDkwNjA5NzAwNjg3NTk4ODIQCBgDEhkKEzUwMDkwNjA5NzAwNjg3NTk4ODIQCBgDGAA%3D:S:ANO1ljIhW_g&gsr=CjuKAzgKGQoTNTAwOTA2MDk3MDA2ODc1OTg4MhAIGAMSGQoTNTAwOTA2MDk3MDA2ODc1OTg4MhAIGAMYAA%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljJmSZ8',
          'Featured': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5009060970068759882',
          'Srila Prabhupada Vani': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mayank.srilaprabhupadavani',
          'ChatEasy - Easy Messaging': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=c.kapps.easymessage.free'
        },
        'Blogs': 'https://mayank-1513.medium.com/',
        'Contact Us': 'https://mayank-chaudhari.web.app/',
      },
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app');
```

```css
* {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.2s all cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.05, 0.36, 1);
  color: #2c3e50;
  cursor: unset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html,
#app {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  background: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav.tr {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: #5555 0 0 0 2px;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 50px;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-item * {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover,
.popup li:hover,
.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #756aee;
  transform: translateY(-5%);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 15px #fff);
}

.nav img {
  height: 195%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav img:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(-4px 8px 10px #756aee);
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #0005;
  background: #fff;
  /* display: none; */
}

.nav-item:hover .popup {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav class="tr">
    <div class="nav">
      <span ref="spacer" class="spacer"></span>
      <menu-item :name="key" :val="val" v-for="(val, key) in menu" :key="'menu' + key" />
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

This works well. However, when I try to add `transition` component and enclose `ul.popup` in `transition` component, it does not behave properly and opacity becomes 0 even when mouse is on the popup menu. Below is the snippet showing this.

```js
const menuItem = {
  props: ['name', 'val'],
  data() {
    return {
      showChild: false
    }
  },
  template: /*html */ `
    <div class="nav-item" @mouseover="showChild=true" @mouseout="showChild=false">
        <span v-if="typeof val === 'string' || val instanceof String">
            <a :href="val" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{name}}</a>
        </span>
        <div v-else>
            {{name}}
            <transition name="fade">
                <ul class="popup" v-show="showChild">
                    <li v-for="(link, name) in val">
                        <a :href="link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    menuItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menu: {
        'Home': '#',
        'Services': {
          'Software Development': 'https://www.upwork.com/signup/create-account/client_contact_freelancer?ciphertext=~0142999d8b15001517&BYOC',
          'Business Training & Frenchise': 'https://www.badabusiness.com/dd/BIMK003866',
          'Organic Marketing Training & Affiliate Program': 'https://leads-arc.web.app/'
        },
        'Our Apps': {
          'All': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=igM4ChkKEzUwMDkwNjA5NzAwNjg3NTk4ODIQCBgDEhkKEzUwMDkwNjA5NzAwNjg3NTk4ODIQCBgDGAA%3D:S:ANO1ljIhW_g&gsr=CjuKAzgKGQoTNTAwOTA2MDk3MDA2ODc1OTg4MhAIGAMSGQoTNTAwOTA2MDk3MDA2ODc1OTg4MhAIGAMYAA%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljJmSZ8',
          'Featured': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5009060970068759882',
          'Srila Prabhupada Vani': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mayank.srilaprabhupadavani',
          'ChatEasy - Easy Messaging': 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=c.kapps.easymessage.free'
        },
        'Blogs': 'https://mayank-1513.medium.com/',
        'Contact Us': 'https://mayank-chaudhari.web.app/',
      },
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app');
```

```css
* {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.2s all cubic-bezier(0.65, 0.05, 0.36, 1);
  color: #2c3e50;
  cursor: unset;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html,
#app {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  background: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav.tr {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: #5555 0 0 0 2px;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 50px;
}

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-item * {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item:hover,
.popup li:hover,
.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #756aee;
  transform: translateY(-5%);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 15px #fff);
}

.nav img {
  height: 195%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav img:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(-4px 8px 10px #756aee);
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #0005;
  background: #fff;
  /* display: none; */
}

.nav-item:hover .popup {
  display: inherit;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav class="tr">
    <div class="nav">
      <span ref="spacer" class="spacer"></span>
      <menu-item :name="key" :val="val" v-for="(val, key) in menu" :key="'menu' + key" />
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was issue with the event that I was listening to. Adding a detailed answer here for benefit of others looking for solution to similar question.

See the WC3 documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseenter_mouseover)

> The mouseover event triggers when the mouse pointer enters the div element, and its child elements.
> The mouseenter event is only triggered when the mouse pointer enters the div element.

changing `@mouseover` to `@mouseenter` and `@mouseout` to `@mouseleave` solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use
`@mouseenter` and `@mouseleave` combination